# JQuery Date Picker Not Showing on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

From what I can see including examples such as this one

[jQuery Datepicker - refresh pickable days based on selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296463/jquery-datepicker-refresh-pickable-days-based-on-selected-option)

This code should work.

Here is where I am calling my external jquery scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I will note in case it matters I am using a bootstrap theme but do not have boot strap datepicker loaded.

When I load the page the date picker loads fine using the code below. (I will note I was using a jquery change event but switched my code to more closely match the above answer in case it was something small I was missing

```
$(function(ready){
    $(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        minDate: "+2W",
        maxDate: "+6W"
      });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <input type="radio" onchange="loadDatePicker()" tabindex="7" class="change" id="radio_1" name="freq" value="1"> Monthly <input type="radio"  onchange="loadDatePicker()" tabindex="8" id="radio_2" class="change" name="freq" value="2"> Bi-Weekly

  <input class="form-control" tabindex="9" onkeyup="slashfunc(this.id)" onchange="datefunc(this.id)" type="text" id="datepicker" value="{{date}}">
```

The outputted HTML is below:

```
<input class="form-control hasDatepicker" tabindex="9" onkeyup="slashfunc(this.id)" onchange="datefunc(this.id)" type="text" id="datepicker" value="">
```

Then I click my radio buttons and the following code is called

```
function loadDatePicker(){
    console.log("test")
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("destroy");
    if($("input[type='radio'][name='freq']:checked").val() == 1){
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        minDate: "+2W",
        maxDate: "+6W"
      });
    }else if($("input[type='radio'][name='freq']:checked").val() == 2){
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        minDate: "+2W",
        maxDate: "+2W10D"
      });
    }
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("refresh");
  }
```

I can see the input change for a second but it quickly goes back

```
<input class="form-control hasDatepicker" tabindex="9" onkeyup="slashfunc(this.id)" onchange="datefunc(this.id)" type="text" id="datepicker" value="">
```

However, now the datepicker no longer comes up when the input for the datepicker is clicked.

Comment: The only likely cause of the datepicker disappearance is `    $('#datepicker').datepicker("destroy");`. Are you sure that your checkbox value is not being manipulated from somewhere else? I have tried your code here : http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/D4AGz/ and it is running as expected.

Comment: @Runcorn I found what was causing the issue. If you have any insight into why this was an issue I would love to know what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this.

It was an external piece of code modifying the DOM.

Part of a chat script I am working on for the same solution included the following lines of code which caused it. (I commented out lines until I found which ones were breaking it)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("body").append('<div id="chat" title="Basic chat"><div id="chats">Please Enter your Name: <input id="username" type="text" ></div></div>');
$("body").append('<div id="chat2" title="Basic chat"><div id="chatc"> </div><div id="chate"><input id="chatb" type="text" ></div></div>');
});
```

For some reason the system objected to this line being between where the date picker was initially declared, and where it was modified.

I moved the entire chat code library above the date picker code and above the jquery-ui library and it all started working as if by magic.