# Enable/Disable Dates in Datepicker Based onChange From Input

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm currently creating a website and have become stuck with an issue with my datepicker.

I am trying to make the datepicker update onChange from an input. Below is the what I have so far. I am returning an array of dates from a google spreadsheet and then disabling these dates from the datepicker using beforeShowDay.

```
 document.getElementById('optionList').addEventListener('change', function 
() {

 alert("hello")

 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(arrayReturnTest).excludedDays();

 document.getElementById("iDate").disabled = false


 });

function arrayReturnTest(arrayDates) {

var days =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var unavailableDays = ["Saturday","Sunday"];

function unavailable(date){

ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();
if ($.inArray(ymd, arrayDates) < 0 && $.inArray(days[day], unavailableDays) < 0) {
    return [true, "enabled", "Book Now"];
} else {
    return [false,"disabled","Booked Out"];
}
}

document.getElementById('input2').value = arrayDates;

$('#iDate').datepicker({
beforeShowDay: unavailable,
showWeek :true,
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
minDate: minDate,
maxDate: '+21d',

});


}
```

This  works as intended and the dates are initially excluded, however if I go into my google spreadsheet and change the dates that are returned in the array, if I change the input the dates do not update in the datepicker and do not reflect the change in the spreadsheet (example below).

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNLux.png)

I've then gone into the google spreadsheet and removed the 20th and set the 13th, so the dates that should now be excluded are the 13th and 27th. I go back into my website change the input but the dates have not changed.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdApD.png)

How do I make the datepicker reflect the changes made to the spreadsheet ?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

After searching the site some more I have now found a solution to my problem.

Here is the link if any body else has the same issue trying to refresh the datepicker.

[jQuery Datepicker - refresh pickable days based on selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296463/jquery-datepicker-refresh-pickable-days-based-on-selected-option)

Spoiler - I needed to add

$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");